# Agregar encabezados en archivo plano txt

Tags: php, sql

Tengo 2 Querys generados uno que es de clientes y otro de proveedores.
ambos son Querys diferentes.

Pero al momento de descargarlos a un archivo plano, me los una un un mismo archivo, pero esten separados por el encacebzado de **clientes** y **proveedores**, tal y como lo muestro en el siguiente ejemplo.

```
***CLIENTES                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
10109473! !GUSTAVO ALBERTO SANINT ALARCON ! ! ! !CLL 38A N 80-53! !2505812 !3162551326 !05001 !ANTIOQUIA !MEDELLIN !                                                                                                                                      
1037574963! !JANET VIVIANA ALVAREZ ! ! ! !CRA115A N 34B -44! !3122042727 ! !05001 !ANTIOQUIA !MEDELLIN !                                                                                                                                                  
1045106908! !VIVIANSY ZAPATA !N!N!N!CARRERA 45 # 30 - 66! !2623042 ! !05001 !ANTIOQUIA !MEDELLIN !                                                                                                                                                        

***PROVEEDORES                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
1128277849! !PLACAS SAN DIEGO ESTEBAN ALONSO SANCHEZ G. !N!N!N!CARRERA 45  37-78! !3812789 !3812789 !05001 !ANTIOQUIA !MEDELLIN !                                                                                                                         
1128422428! !JUANITA ARROYAVE GAVIRIA !N!N!N!CRA 30 # 7A-167! !3541058 ! !05001 !ANTIOQUIA !MEDELLIN !
```

Estos son la sintaxis de ambas consultas:

```
$sql=" select 
        CASE WHEN x0.sw_persona_juridica=1 THEN
        SUBSTRING(cast( x0.cedula as varchar(20)) FROM 1 FOR 9) ELSE cast(x0.cedula as varchar(20)) END nit ,
        CASE WHEN x0.sw_persona_juridica=1 THEN
        SUBSTRING(cast( x0.cedula as varchar(20)) FROM 9 FOR 2) ELSE '' END  dv,
        x0.nombres ,x0.apellidos,x0.telefono,x0.celular as tel_alterno,
        x0.dir_cliente,x1.c_ciudad as cod_ciudad,x2.d_departamento as departamento,
        x1.d_ciudad as ciudad,x0.sw_persona_juridica as tipo_tercero,x0.email,
        c_doc_cliente as tipo_doc,x0.id_alterno_cliente,x0.sw_regimen_comun,
        x0.sw_regimen_simplificado,x0.sw_gran_contribuyente
        FROM m_clientes x0 ,m_ciudades_mahalo x1,m_departamentos_mahalo x2
        WHERE x0.c_ciudad=x1.c_ciudad 
        AND x1.c_departamento=x2.c_departamento
        $rangoFechas ;";
        p_query($sql);
        //echo "<br><br>--30--<br>".$sql;

        $vectorDeConsultas[$idxDeConsultas] = $sql;
        $idxDeConsultas = $idxDeConsultas + 1;  

    /*$sql1=" select x0.nit nit2,x0.digito_verifica dv2,x0.d_proveedor,x0.direccion dir2,x0.telefono tel2,
        x0.telefono as tel_alterno2 ,e_mail as e_mail2,x1.c_ciudad as cod_ciudad2,
        x2.d_departamento as departamento2,x1.d_ciudad as ciudad2
        FROM m_proveedores x0 ,m_ciudades_mahalo x1,m_departamentos_mahalo x2
        WHERE x0.c_ciudad=x1.c_ciudad 
        AND x1.c_departamento=x2.c_departamento;";
        //$rangoFechas ;";
        p_query($sql1);
        //echo "<br><br>--30--<br>".$sql;

        $vectorDeConsultas[$idxDeConsultas] = $sql1;
        $idxDeConsultas = $idxDeConsultas + 1;
```

Medienta un While despues de generar la consulta. hago un recorrido y le asigno a cada variable sus respectivo valores
ejemplo:

```
$nit=round(trim($registro['nit']),0);
$DV=trim($registro['dv']);  .
```

Finalizo llenando un Array con esta información:

```
$ArrayPlanoTERCEROACTIVO[$j][1]=$nit;//NIT  (SIN PUNTOS, COMAS NI DIGITO DE VERIFICACIÓN)
$linea2 = $linea2.str_pad($ArrayPlanoTERCEROACTIVO[$j][1], 13).$separador; 
$ArrayPlanoTERCEROACTIVO[$j][2]=$DV;//DV (DIGITO DE VERIFICACIÓN)
$linea2 = $linea2.str_pad($ArrayPlanoTERCEROACTIVO[$j][2], 1).$separador; 
fwrite($ff, $linea2);
```

En este caso solo me pinta la información de clientes pero sin el encabezado

Necesito que en el mismo archivo carguen la información de ambas consultas separadas por los encabezados anteriormente mencioanados

Answer (score 0):

**ACTUALIZADO CÓDIGO CORRECTO:**

Hay un error de concatenación.

**Código erróneo:**

Si te fijas en este fragmento de tu código, en la **línea 4**, al hacer `$linea2 = $linea2.str_pad($ArrayPlanoTERCEROACTIVO[$j][2], 1).$separador;`  le quitas el valor anterior, debería ser:  `$linea2 .= $linea2.str_pad($ArrayPlanoTERCEROACTIVO[$j][2], 1).$separador;` o sea concatenar usando el `.=`

```
$ArrayPlanoTERCEROACTIVO[$j][1]=$nit;//NIT  (SIN PUNTOS, COMAS NI DIGITO DE VERIFICACIÓN)
$linea2 = $linea2.str_pad($ArrayPlanoTERCEROACTIVO[$j][1], 13).$separador; 
$ArrayPlanoTERCEROACTIVO[$j][2]=$DV;//DV (DIGITO DE VERIFICACIÓN)
$linea2 = $linea2.str_pad($ArrayPlanoTERCEROACTIVO[$j][2], 1).$separador; //aquí estas reiniciando la variable $linea2 desde cero al usar $linea2 = ...
```

**Código correcto:**

```
$ArrayPlanoTERCEROACTIVO[$j][1]=$nit;//NIT  (SIN PUNTOS, COMAS NI DIGITO DE VERIFICACIÓN)
$linea2 .= str_pad($ArrayPlanoTERCEROACTIVO[$j][1], 13).$separador; //como antes pones $line2 = $linea2.str_pad supongo que ya $linea2 existe más arriba en el código, si no es así aquí quitas el punto, pues sería el primer contenido que agregas a la variable que iras concatenando
$ArrayPlanoTERCEROACTIVO[$j][2]=$DV;//DV (DIGITO DE VERIFICACIÓN)
$linea2 .= str_pad($ArrayPlanoTERCEROACTIVO[$j][2], 1).$separador; 
fwrite($ff, $linea2);
```